# Google Optimize - how many times to set the experiment ID and variant ID?

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-optimize

I use Google Optimize with server-side A/B experiments. Server-side code targets audiences, consistently serves the appropriate variant to each user, etc. I only use the Optimize interface to create experiments, set objectives, create variants, and view reports.
I configure Optimize as described in the [Server-side experiments with Universal Analytics (analytics.js)](https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments?hl=en&technology=analyticsjs) documentation.

The server-side code must set the experiment and variation IDs and send this data with a `pageview` event:

```
// 3. Set the experiment ID and variant ID.
ga('set', 'exp', '$experimentId.$variationId');

// 4. Send a pageview hit to Google Analytics.
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The question is how many times to set an experiment and variation IDs? Let's assume there is an experiment on Homepage. On the Homepage there is a link to the Contacts page. The Contacts page is not part of the experiment. The scenario id the following:

1. The user opens the Homepage and gets the Variant 1 - set the experiment and variation ID
2. User clicks the link and gets to the Contacts page - **do we need to set the experiment and variation IDs?**
3. User once again opens the Homepage - **do we need to set the experiment and variation IDs?**

What is the correct way to set the experiment and variation IDs?

1. Set only **once** on the page where the split has happen
2. Set only on the page that is a part of the experiment (every time a user opens this page)
3. Set on all pages until the experiment ends